# Close userform with arrow keys and open a new one

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have this below code which I use for viewing images on Userform, depending on Target.Value in `Range("A1:A200")`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyPic As String


MyPath = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\"
On Error GoTo error_handler:


If Intersect(Target, Range("a1:a200")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
MyPic = Target.Value & ".jpg"

UserForm2.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(MyPath & MyPic)
UserForm2.Show vbModeless

error_handler:
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

The problem I am encountering with this script is that I am not able to change my active cell with my arrow keys.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the userform, though modeless, still has the focus.

There's a solution here that worked for me: [cpearson.com  SetFocus](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SetFocus.aspx)